# Dio response byte image not converting to Uint8List, Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am trying to solve this issue since so log and not getting any solution.

```
final _response = await _apiService.getCall(ApiConstants.url_user_qr + query);
  if (_response?.statusCode == 200) {
    var a = Utf8Decoder().convert(_response?.data.codeUnits);
  }
```

I tried all the possible solution which I get over internet. Help really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

After more research I found a solution

```
dio.get(path, queryParameters: queryParams, options: Options(responseType: ResponseType.bytes));
```

Comment: I have tried this code snippet but, got :

Error: DioError [connection error]: The connection errored: The XMLHttpRequest onError callback was called. This typically indicates an error on the network layer.